# Old English Etymology

Tags: etymology

Recently in my research I came across an O.E. word, 'ingebringan' out of a dictionary wherein the scholar translated it as "to bring in". It seems to me that in a verbatim translation, he left out the suffix 'an' which on both nouns and adjectives means 'of or belonging to' or it may also mean 'one'. The word ge in O.E. can mean to, into or together. Can a scholar out there clarify this for me. Thank you

Comment: Do you have a citation showing the use of _ingebringan_? What is the name of the dictionary?

Comment: Source: A Concise Anglo-Saxon Dictionary by John Clark Hall, 1916, page 176. On the internet

Comment: Thank you. I'm afraid I can't really add anything. It isn't in any of the couple of Old English books that I have, and probably isn't that common.

Answer (score 5):

*-an* is the Old English verbal suffix indicating the infinitive, e.g. *singan*, "to sing", *drincan*, "to drink", *niman*, "to take". (Compare *singen, trinken, nehmen* in Modern German.) The scholar's analysis seems correct to me.

**Edit:** I overlooked the other part of the question. *ġe-* could be a simple intensifier, but further context is in order if we want to be certain, as it can mean [a number of things](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ge-#Old_English).

Comment: Are you familiar with German? Ge- usually signifies a participle form . Also OP's concern about the ending 'an' is also misguided... if one were to be familiar with German infinitive endings - OE being heavy Germanic.

Comment: @d'alar'cop yes I am, and yes it does, and yes that is one of the things it does in Old English, too (as you will see by following my link). In fact we have a [dedicated question](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/22710/300) on that. However, the prefix alone does not usually a participle make. Note how it's *gelost* and not *gelosian*, or back to German again *gebracht* and not *gebringen*.

Comment: But not all OE past participles were formed with _ge-_.

Comment: Yes, and then there's that.

Comment: I found this reference and I thought to add it here: "an, suffix. I. Derivative. 1. repr. L. anus, ana,-anum, of or belonging to. Orig. in M.E. -ain, or (after i ) -en, after OFr., but later refash. -an. Esp. added to proper names; 'belonging to a place', as Oxonian, etc.; 'following a founder', or 'a system', as Lutheran, Anglican..." Source: Shorter Oxford English Dict., Vol. 1, A-M, 1933, Oxford University Press. In understanding Modern English the word 'bring' is regarded now as a verb. But was it always thus?