# Old English sounds and Germanic languages

Tags: germanic-languages

What languages still use the 'ge' prefix that was part of the Old English grammatical structure?  I've searched and found German, but am not sure that is the only one which still does.  I'm interested, because I am involved in a conversation regarding how we know what Old English sounded like. (I've seen this question: [What we've gelost — why doesn't English use the prefix "ge-"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22700/what-weve-gelost-why-doesnt-english-use-the-prefix-ge) but it didn't seem to provide the answer I'm seeking.)

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22700/what-weve-gelost-why-doesnt-english-use-the-prefix-ge

Comment: Thank you, J O S H!    I saw that link before I asked my question, but it didn't seem to provide the answer I'm seeking.  Thanks for your help, though.

Comment: This is not really a question about English, maybe better for linguistics.stackexchange.com? In any case both Dutch and Afrikaans also have "ge-".

Comment: Leasnam does answer this at the linked question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is for the linguistics.stackexchange.com.