# what does "pace someone" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

What does ***"pace someone"*** mean after the consideration of an idea? Does it mean "respectfully in contrast with that person's idea"?

New York is a so beautiful city (pace James).

Comment: It's mentioned here: [What are the historical processes of preposition coining in English?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6155/what-are-the-historical-processes-of-preposition-coining-in-english/54045#54045) Can you post what a dictionary has to say?

Comment: Thank you @sumelic . Almost all dictionaries define it as "speed, step, and the like".

Comment: This community is not your dictionary service. Please see the definition of [pace](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pace) as a preposition:contrary to the opinion of —usually used as an expression of deference to someone's contrary opinion

Comment: Could you please say where you found that citation or usage of *pace*. Indeed it does look a bit peculiar, I am not familiar with that usage. Adding another example will probably save your question, when I read the title I understood something quite different, so I'd edit the title too if I were you. Otherwise users will say the meaning can be find in any dictionary... oops someone already has. I had no idea *pace* was also a preposition.

Comment: @sumelic could you please post the answer?

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pace#Etymology_2

Answer (score 2):

Yes!

***Pace*** - pronounced either /ˈpɑˌtʃeɪ/ or ˈpeɪˌsi/ and meaning 'With due deference to (a named person or authority); despite. (classical Latin *pāce*, ablative of *pāx* peace, as used both in phrases with possessive pronoun and in phrases with genitive of the person whose leave or favour is sought)' OED.

1863   Fraser's Mag. Nov. 662/1   *Mendelssohn was an artist passionately devoted to his art, who (pâce Dr. Trench) regarded art as virtù.*

1911   Chambers's Jrnl. Nov. 720/1   *The colour [of fruit]..is a tacit invitation (pace the gardener) to the feast.*

1995   Computers & Humanities 29 404/1,   *I do not believe, pace Peirce and Derrida, that it is signs all the way down, and that, pace Dennett, there is no distinctive human intentionality, and that, pace almost everyone, thinking is fundamentally linguistic*.