# When should you use "despite" over "inspite", and vice versa?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms, discourse-markers

Most dictionaries suggest that *inspite* and *despite* are synonymous, but are there any specific instances when their usage is not interchangeable?

Comment: Related: [is it “despite” or “despite of”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5634/) (Scroll down to the second graph.)

Comment: @Reg: (+1)Nice post there, but I am still curious if there is any sentence or phrase where inspite cannot be replaced by despite or vice-versa.

Comment: "Despite" strikes me as a little bit more formal, but I can't think of any contexts in which they are not interchangeable. In older English, you could render "in spite of him" as "in his spite", but that would get you strange looks if you said it now.

Comment: Related ["Despite vs in spite of"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/122649/despite-vs-in-spite-of)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would suggest that *inspite* — as written in your question — is not in fact a word.

I think you must mean *in spite of*, which is directly interchangeable with *despite*.

> *He went for a walk in spite of the rain.*
>
> *He went for a walk despite the rain.*

I am not aware of any real difference between the two options, though I tend to use *despite* purely for efficiency of words.

Comment: I agree - especially with "in spite" vs "inspite" - see here: http://www.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/inspite.html

Comment: Thanks for your link, @MikeGoatly; it's brilliantly concise.

Comment: Ya I have always been confused about space between 'in' and 'spite'. So what you mean to suggest is that in-spite cannot be without an immediate 'of'?

Comment: That's right. And without your hyphen, too. Three words: 'in spite of'.

Comment: On another note, spite means "to intentionally annoy, hurt, or upset." Any idea how does it connect to 'in-spite'.

Comment: Well, if you do something to spite someone, as you said it means you do that thing knowing that the person would wish you not to. Consider that person a situation - a rainy day, for example. The expectation on a rainy day is that you will stay in. If you go out in spite of the rain - it is like you are acting without paying appropriate respect/attention to the situation. It's crude, but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 8):

It is true that "inspite" is not a word.  The difference between "in spite of" and "despite" is more in connotation than in efficiency:

"In spite of" usually connotes a degree of contempt or rebellion.  For example, one could say, "In spite of the supervisor's mandate, Pauline went out for lunch."  This suggests that Pauline does not think highly of the supervisor's mandate.

"Despite" is usually more of a neutral contradiction.  "Despite the supervisor's mandate, Pauline went out for lunch."  This shows that the supervisor has not affected Pauline's plan for lunch either way; she just doesn't care.

These ought not be confused with the infinitive verb "to spite", which is meant as a direct rebellion:  "I punched him in the face to spite him."

Answer (score -1):

If you find a pair such as "despite sth" and the variant "in spite of sth" you may assume that the shorter one is in current use and the longer one on the wane. There is no difference between the two, according to Longman DCE.

Comment: _In spite of_ and _despite_ are in fact more or less equally common. Neither is on the wane.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet  I did not check it before, I said it from general observation. But now I checked Ngram viewer and it confirms my view.