# "Despite" vs "In spite of"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, discourse-markers

Are *despite* and *in spite of* interchangeable? I prefer *despite* but the alternative sometimes scans better.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of *in spite of* and *despite* are interchangeable. Both expressions are [**discourse markers**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discourse_marker) or [**linkers**](https://sites.google.com/site/maycaingles2011/writing/linkers-and-connectors). *Despite* is slightly more formal than *in spite of*.

**Despite**

- a) Despite **the age** difference, she decided to marry him.

  b) Despite **being** twenty years younger, she decided to marry him.

  c) Despite **the fact that** she was 20 years younger, they got married.

  d) Despite **their age** difference, they decided to get married.

**in spite of**

- a) In spite of **the age** difference, she decided to marry him.

  b) In spite of **being** twenty years younger, she decided to marry him

  c) In spite of **the fact that** she was 20 years younger, they got married.

  d) In spite of **their age** difference, they decided to get married.

I would argue that *in spite of* and *despite* are interchangeable and their position can be either at the beginning of the sentence or in the middle. The only difference being that *in spite of* is a longer expression and requires an additional preposition, *of*. *Despite* does not require *of* and as a result is shorter.

Consequently, in sentences (b), (c) and (d) I would opt for "despite". But that is my opinion, and either way they are all grammatically correct.

Comment: I agree that they are mostly interchangeable, but in some cases where actual spite is implied, ‘in spite of’ seems better to me: “Teenagers often have messy rooms despite their parents’ warnings” (no direct spite), but “Teenagers often go to rave parties in spite of their parents’ orders that they are not to go”. The difference is minimal, but I would always use ‘in spite of’ in the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are. But *despite* seems to the one commonly used. *In spite of* was more popular in the past, but according to this [Google Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20spite%20of,%20despite&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) it's use has been in decline.

Answer (score 0):

While both terms are synonymous with *notwithstanding* and *without regard to*, they also both can convey an element of **defiance** or **contempt**. A downside of "in spite of" (in addition to being longer) is that it's **potentially more ambiguous**.

Consider: "I invited John to join me on my trip to the Department of Motor Vehicles to renew my driver's license, in spite of his having had an affair with my wife last year."

Or: "In spite of his having defeated me in the election, I invited him to dinner to experience my wife's cooking."

I would opt for *despite* whenever there could be any ambiguity.

PS: The "wife" references are gratuitous. I grew up on Henny Youngman jokes.