# The use of the genitive in: We had a good time despite "its" raining

Tags: pronouns, subordinate-clauses, discourse-markers

"We had a good time despite its raining."

Why does the genitive pronoun not work here, yet in the majority of examples we have a choice between accusative and genitive pronouns:-

> We had a good time despite him being ill. OK
>
> We had a good time despite his being ill. OK
>
> We had a good time despite them arguing. OK
>
> We had a good time despite their arguing. OK
>
> We had a good time despite it raining. OK
>
> We had a good time despite its raining. NOT OK.

And what exactly is "it"?

Also am I correct in thinking that *their arguing* is a noun phrase, whereas *them arguing* is a non-finite subordinate clause? And if that is true then with a sentence like "We had a good time despite arguing" what is *despite arguing*? Is it an NP or a non-finite clause? Or is it a Schroedinger's cat?

Comment: You can't use "it's" (which you by the way misspelled), i.e. present tense in conjunction with "had" because this is something that already occured. Correct way of saying your sentence would be: "We had a good time despite it having been raining." Or even better, skip "raining" and just mention that the weather was bad: "We had a good time despite the awful weather."

Comment: @silkfire - are you sure OP misspelled *its*? Please reread the context and OP's examples.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdiscourse-markers%5D+despite = tagged discourse marker posts that mention "despite"

Comment: related [When should you use “despite” over “inspite”, and vice versa?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21153/when-should-you-use-despite-over-inspite-and-vice-versa) and ["despite" vs "in spite of"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/122649/despite-vs-"in-spite-of")

Comment: The dummy it does not have a possessive form. That is sort of the whole point. It is a dummy placeholder. It is not a thing, and cannot possess. [What does “it” refer to in “it's raining”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5758/what-does-it-refer-to-in-its-raining)

Comment: @Mari-LouA That kind of linking's dangerous round here because someone'll think it''s a duplicate and try and close it ;-)

Comment: @RegDwigнt, thecrease It has marginal accpetability to me ...

Comment: @Araucaria I was helping the OP tell the truth and I wrote *related*. It can't be closed as a duplicate because the OP is asking something quite different.

Comment: Could you add to your list the following, please old bean? *We had a good time despite being ill.* and *We had a good time despite him*. If you do, I might offer a bounty! [oo!]

Comment: @Mari-LouA *I* know that, but I thought I'd better make sure anyone visiting did too! :)

Answer (score 2):

*[Despite](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/despite)* as used in these sentences is a preposition

> Without being affected by; in spite of

[*Oxford Dictionaries Online*]

The words that follow *despite* are objects of the preposition

> 1. We had a good time despite him being ill. [*him* pronoun object, *being ill* participle modifier of *him*]
> 2. We had a good time despite his being ill. [*being ill* gerund object, *his* possessive of *being ill*]
> 3. We had a good time despite them arguing. [same as 1.]
> 4. We had a good time despite their arguing. [same as 2.]
> 5. We had a good time despite it raining. [implied object and defining clause *...despite the fact that it was raining*]
> 6. We had a good time despite its raining. NOT OK.

The pronoun *[it](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/it)* in the above phrases is effectively an indefinite placeholder to describe a state of affairs

> Used in the normal subject position in statements about time, distance, or weather

[*Oxford Dictionaries Online*]

While other pronouns in the examples (*him, them*) are actual entities to which the writer is referring, there is no real *it* in the raining examples. And there is no *it* to possess the raining.

Comment: Contrast _The dog gave him a good bite despite its training._