# despite / in spite of?

Tags: phrase-usage, confusables, discourse-markers

I could not sleep ____  very tired .

Here, I tried:

1. I could not sleep *despite* I was very tired .
2. I could not sleep *in spite of* very tired

Which one is correct?

Comment: _Despite_ and _in spite of_ both require either a noun (_despite the rain_) or a gerund (_despite being very tired_). Tensed clauses won't work, and neither will predicate adjectives.

Comment: related: 1. [When should you use “despite” over “inspite”, and vice versa?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21153/when-should-you-use-despite-over-inspite-and-vice-versa) 2. [“Despite” vs “In spite of”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/122649/despite-vs-in-spite-of) 3. [When should you use “despite” over “inspite”, and vice versa?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21153/when-should-you-use-despite-over-inspite-and-vice-versa?rq=1)

Comment: But the best post is this one: [Is it “despite” or “despite of”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5634/is-it-despite-or-despite-of)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a thread on this on the English Language Learners site, [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/506/usage-in-spite-of-and-despite-of).

Also, neither of these works in your sentence. You need to say "in spite of *the fact that* I was very tried" or "despite *the fact that* I was very tired".

You could also say "I could not sleep *although* I was very tired".