# How to use despite and inspite?

Tags: conjunctions

Do the following sentences use 'despite' correctly:
a) Despite having fractured his arm, Ravi insisted on playing the match.
b) Despite fracturing his arm, Ravi insisted on playing the match.

Comment: Duplicate of [When should you use “despite” over “inspite”, and vice versa?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21153/when-should-you-use-despite-over-inspite-and-vice-versa).

Answer (score 5):

Both of those are fine. *Despite* functions as a preposition, and takes a Noun Phrase, very often a clause headed by a gerund (*-ing* form)

The past form *despite having fractured* is more precise, but the simple form *despite fracturing* is perfectly good, and I think most people would say it in ordinary speech. The NOW (News on the Web) corpus shows 8201 instances of *despite having [pp]* against 180,158 of *despite [verb]ing*, though there's no easy way of determining how many of the latter could have use the *having* form.

You mention *in spite* in your title, but not in the question. *In spite of* (three words) can always replace *despite*. It is much less common in the NOW corpus: 3883 of *in spite of [verb]ing*, 219 of *in spite of [pp]*. But I think it is more common in speech.

Comment: It might be worth adding that that this proposition could equally be expressed as “Despite his/a fractured arm, Ravi insisted ... match.”.