# Despite in a sentence

Tags: grammar

Normally, I only use "despite" with a noun followed but now I see this sentence: "despite people having different opinions, we still managed to get everyone on board". 
Is the use of "despite" in this sentence correct or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use despite and inspite?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/429649/how-to-use-despite-and-inspite)

Comment: A gerund phrase qualifies as a noun phrase.

Comment: But your sentence *does* have a noun (*people*) following *despite*. If you remove the word *people* then it would a verb following *despite*. (Which would still be fine.)

Comment: The use of "despite" in that sentence is fine.

FYI, "despite" with a noun *…followed* should always be *…following*. Do you see the difference?

Answer (score 1):

"Despite" is used before a noun, a phrase functioning as a noun, or pronoun. A gerund verb phrase such as "having different opinions" functions as a noun.

[In spite, despite and although](https://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/in-spite-despite-and-although)
[Gerund phrase](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/gerund-phrase/)