# Is "despite" outdated?

Tags: prepositions, word-usage

A friend of mine, a respected linguist, mentioned recently that "despite" (prep) is outdated.  Whilst it is true that I hardly ever hear someone using the word in ordinary conversation, I still hear it in scientific seminars, lectures, congresses, etc and I also come across it in technical texts once in a while. 
What I mean here is "despite" and not "despite of" or "in despite of" which are clearly archaic. The search I've done includes the mainstream dictionaries (ODO, TFD, Merriam-Webster, etc) and they don't mention the word being outdated.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Well, [here's](https://books.google.com/ngrams/chart?content=despite&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdespite%3B%2Cc0%5D) the Google Ngram for *despite*. I don't know what it would look like if it was becoming outdated, but I doubt it would look like this:
[image]

Comment: I'm surprised.  What about its use in ordinary conversation, do you ever hear it?  Do you use it?

Comment: Hard to say whether I hear it or use it (because I don't monitor my conversation like that) but if I didn't I'd expect to feel that it was strange or unusual and I don't (in British English at least). Despite seems quite a normal word.

Comment: @centaurus I definitely heard it in an interview I had the other day. It's also generally on the lists of different kinds of "linkers" for students doing English for Academic Purposes, IELTS, CAE and the like - one of the reasons that I decided to check it out.

Comment: @Centaurus I still hear people say it, and I use it myself.

Comment: @Centaurus Same here.  I use it and hear other people using it in conversation.  I think your friend needs to go back and take a look at what made them say that to you.  "Despite of" and "in despite of" aren't completely outdated either, though they're probably at least beginning to head in that general direction.  (They're becoming kind of an elitist English teacher thing these days; the word "despite" though, in and of itself, is something almost everybody uses sooner or later.)

Comment: I use it frequently.  Though I often change it up with "in spite of" so as to not sound repetitive.  Admittedly, I use the word "despite" far more often when writing than speaking in everyday conversation.

Comment: Even more to the point, here's a [more complete picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ceO6O.gif). Not only is *despite* quickly gaining momentum, but the only real alternative *in spite of* is just as quickly losing in popularity.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Saved me a job, Was just wondering about that right this second!

Comment: It's from [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/5652/300) to a related question. This site has a graph for everything.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Nice post. I was wondering before you put that link in whether *in spite of* was going to be losing out because of word counts in academic journals and the like ... It's two extra words, after all.

Comment: What earthshaking events occurred around 1950-1960? https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=despite%2Cin+spite+of&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cdespite%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdespite%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BDespite%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cin%20spite%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bin%20spite%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BIn%20spite%20of%3B%2Cc0#t4%3B%2Cdespite%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdespite%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BDespite%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cin%20spite%20of%3B%2Cc1%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bin%20spite%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BIn%20spite%20of%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I fixed the link to the ngram, but looks like the image you had has gone missing. (see revision history)

Comment: @Heartspring Thanks

Answer (score 19):

[Uses of despite found on the web in the last hour](https://www.google.com/search?q=despite&tbs=qdr:h)

[Uses of despite found on news sites in the last hour](https://www.google.com/search?q=despite&tbs=qdr:h&tbm=nws)

It's alive and well.

Comment: If anything, it's a go-to filler word for novice academic writers.

Comment: Also [recent uses of "despite" found on Stack Exchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=despite) perhaps?

Comment: [Despite](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=despite): 1058. [Bro](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=bro):68

Comment: your first link shows no results for me: Jan 07, 17:32 GMT

Comment: @Octopus ah, perhaps a side-effect of google's approach to geolocation. Could you try again please and tell me if it works after my edit?

Comment: I will check back on this answer in 50 years and if it ends up turning out wrong you will have hell to pay mister.

Answer (score 3):

***is it still being used?***

An example, from the Associated Press, dated tomorrow
(so, it seems not only is it being used now, it will still be used in the future!)

> American businesses ramped up hiring last month, in the latest sign that the nation’s economy is expanding despite worries about global growth.