# Is there a database of word families?

Tags: resources, inflections

Is there any where that I can download the database/dictionary for word families? For example one line of it will have something like this:

> Pellucid, pellucidity, pellucidly, pellucidness

A top google search gives me the [Word Family Framework](https://www.learnenglish.org.uk/wff/index.html#) of British Council. But it only contains popular words. I also have tried all the links in [Is there an online sample sentence database or search engine?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/3557/80007) question, but they don't give me what I need.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because It's a request for resources.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock [but but but but...](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3557/is-there-an-online-sample-sentence-database-or-search-engine)

Comment: Don't (good) dictionaries do this?

Comment: Well the OP wants to download it. I don't think that the online dictionaries have that functionality.

Comment: You can download a pdf of a good dictionary...

Comment: @Silenus I want to extract the data actually

Comment: how many families do you need? This one has around 15000: http://www.lexically.net/downloads/BNC_wordlists/e_lemma.txt

Comment: @V0ight hmm, this one seems trivial. I need a list that lists *academic* as a word in the family *academy*, not listing *academic* and *academy* as two separate words

Comment: @Ooker ~ good point, I didn't even look through it haha. How about this one: http://enroots.neocities.org/ Has 28000 word families supposedly

Comment: @V0ight yess that's what I'm looking for. How did you google it? Make it an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: ["english word families"](https://www.google.com/search?q=database+word+families+lemmas&oq=database&aqs=chrome.1.69i59l3j69i57j69i60j69i65.4052j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22english+word+families%22&start=10) -- top of the second page :D

Comment: This question is too old to migrate or I would have put it on Meta. This question is not on-topic for the main site.

Comment: Doesn't the unix aspell system allow getting leal extensions from a root?

Comment: @Mitch isn't it just a spell checker? What is *leal*? And how can I get the extensions from a root?

Comment: @Ooker Yes, aspell is a spell checker but it is complex enough to print out things. You can get a word list from it, it has a list of suffixes, so I'm guessing that there might be a way to print off roots possibly and maybe the legal suffixes for each root, I don't know, just a suggestion to research. As to 'leal' I probably meant 'all'.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a question suited to ELU.Meta rather than ELU. And showing instances of other questions going against site policy isn't respecting the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page has a list of ~28,000 word families: http://enroots.neocities.org/

> "This list is a combination of lists 1 to 25, 32 and 33 of the BNC/COCA word family lists by Paul Nation. Nonsense words (lists 26 to 30), proper nouns (list 31) and abbreviations (list 34) were not included."

---

If you'd like all 34 lists then check out the links at the bottom of this page: 
http://www.laurenceanthony.net/software/antwordprofiler/

specifically the link: "BNC/COCA family lists + extras (Version 2.00)"

More information on the word families by Paul Nation: http://www.victoria.ac.nz/lals/about/staff/publications/paul-nation/Information-on-the-BNC_COCA-word-family-lists.pdf

Paul Nation home page: http://www.victoria.ac.nz/lals/about/staff/paul-nation

Comment: searching for `"english word families"` and the result shows up in page 3...

Answer (score 2):

The OED can be interrogated with the search term, for example, **pellucid***

1. pellucid, adj. and n.  1563
   ...Transmitting or allowing the passage of light; translucent, transparent....
2. pellucid zone in pellucid, adj. and n.  1890
   ...= zona pellucidazona....
3. pellucidity, n.  1642
   ...The quality or condition of being pellucid; transparency, clarity, lucidity. Now chiefly figurative....
4. pellucidly, adv.  1754
   ...In a pellucid manner; transparently, clearly, lucidly. Now frequently figurative....
5. pellucidness, n.  1684
   ...Pellucid quality or condition; pellucidity....
6. † pellucido-, comb. form  1847
   ...Forming adjectives with the sense ‘pellucidly’....
7. pellucido-punctate in † pellucido-, comb. form  1847
   ...marked with pellucid spots....
8. pellucid-punctulate in punctulate, adj.